# AWS RDS Mysql with benstalk Hibernate app: Character encoding issue - chars are replaced by?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, amazon-web-services

I use mysql 5.5.27 on amazon rds and the table that we want to update has got collation set to utf8 - utf8_unicode_ci

Also, on hibernate side I have set below

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
```

Besides, for tomcat7 that runs on amazon aws beanstalk, I have set -Dfile.encoding=utf-8

And still the column (varchar(250)) has characters replaced with ?

For example, for the string: Tuljapur, Osmānābād, Osmanabad, Maharashtra, 413600, भारत गणराज्य India

I see this in the database: NH211, Tuljapur, Osm?n?b?d, Osmanabad, Maharashtra, 413600, ???? ??????? India

Appreciate your quick help.

Comment: Found answer to the above after spending many hours.  And answer is: While setting field value in setter method of hibernate, I used URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")  and while getting the string in getter method I used URLDecoder.decode(string, "UTF-8").